# Read directory contents using Javascript locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a standard folder structure for a web app.

- css
- js
- img
- asetts
- lib

index.html

Inside my assets folder I have a bunch of plain text files and I would like to first be able to list the filenames using Javascript, so I can store the URI's in the model, and read from them later on the in the application.  I want all of this happening client side.

Answer (score 1):

(Client-side) JavaScript does not have access to the file system like that.

This is not possible without some kind of browser plugin.

Comment: Is there any alternative then? How would I serve up static content like that without the need for a server?

Comment: Without the need for a server? No. Nothing reliable.

Comment: It is possible to read the contents of a directory using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) instead of a browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the textfiles in the local folder.

```
function read()
{
    var xHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //replace textfile_url with the relative url of your text file
    xHR.open("GET", "textfile_url", true);
    xHR.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(xHR.readyState === 4)
        {
            //all your text is in the next line
            var text = xHR.responseText;

        }
    }

    xHR.send();
}
```